# Do any local churches in the lands evangelized by the apostles celebrate a particular feast of that apostle?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, apostles, feasts, apostolic-age

In Catholic and/or Orthodox traditions are there any liturgical feast(s) that are celebrated by local dioceses in the regions evangelized by the apostles in the honor of any of the apostles? The feasts in question should reflect an historical event of an apostle during the [apostolic age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolic_Age) and not found in the General Roman Calendar or its' equivalent in the Orthodox Churches.

For example the Catholic Church in Malta celebrates the [Feast of the Shipwreck of St. Paul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/47644/how-is-the-feast-of-the-shipwreck-of-st-paul-celebrated-in-the-domestic-church) on February 10 each year.

Another example could be the Chair of the [Church of Saint Peter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Saint_Peter) is celebrated every 21 February in Antakya, Turkey!

[image: Saint Peter’s Church at Antioch (from the 4th or 5th century)]

Saint Peter’s Church at Antioch (from the 4th or 5th century)