# How is the Feast of the Shipwreck of St Paul celebrated in the domestic church, that is, within the Catholic family in Malta?

Tags: catholicism, paul-apostle, tradition, church-local, feasts

The Catholic Archdiocese of Malta celebrates the Feast of the Shipwreck of St Paul on February 10 each year.

I would like to know if the domestic church has any traditional ways of celebrating this feast within the family at Malta?